# Android Biometric unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric, android-unit-testing

I need to write Unit test cases for Android Biometric prompt. I tried to search many links but didn't get the proper direction. Need to write unit test cases for UI Biometric is visible or not. Do I have permission to show biometric or not etc. Can someone please provide the suggestions?

Comment: Create an interface as an abstraction and mock/stub the interface. You shouldn't need to test platform code directly just your own behaviour of how it interacts with it.

Comment: @MarkKeen Do you have any reference ?